# After updating to Rails 5 and Devise 4.0.0.rc1, the devise authenticate_user! method is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I had a rails app which was running perfectly with devise 3 and rails 4. I updated rails to 5 and it gave `DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated`. So i had to change the devise version to 4.0.0.rc1.

Now it seems like the devise is not generating the methods like `authenticate_user!`, `is_admin` etc..

I am getting the following error

```
Before process_action callback :authenticate_user! has not been defined (ArgumentError)
```

I tried everything including, uninstall devise and install again, then tried to create a separate model from scratch and still the methods are not defined.

Any ideas please ?

Comment: Are there any updates on this? I'm trying to implement gradual engagement on rails 5 and get similar errors following the wiki.

Comment: I am not sure what errors you get exactly, for my case it was a feature upgrade in rails5 where it can just be fixed by adding an additional parameter, i have mentioned it in the accepted answer.

I could find out the issue by inspecting the files by putting a `binding.pry` debug statement

If you are running it from terminal you may get a file path and line number which throws the error, so just don't be afraid to dive into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could identify the issue, in rails 5, there will be an exception if the skipping method is not defined at the time of calling unless we add `:unless` condition.

Comment: can you provide more details how you fixed this please?

Comment: for now I set `config.eager_load = false` in `config/environments/production.rb` as a workaround.

Comment: The issue was that in rails 5, the skip callback option will throw an exception if the method which want to skip is not defined.

In my code i am skipping the authenticate_user! method on initialization of the app, at that time the method is not defined, devise defines the methods later.

If we want rails not to throw an exception, we have to use another clause like follows:

`Devise::SessionsController.skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, raise: false`

Comment: This is utterly confusing. When are you skipping this? Why? How does this actually address the issue?

Comment: @YannickSchuchmann I have no idea why that worked but thank you.

Answer (score 13):

The answer for this is to simply change:

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
```

to ---

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, raise: false
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4207
https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/issues/621

Comment: Is this safe, seems kinda hacky?

Answer (score 1):

Until rails5 support lands in devise itself, you can try using this fork:

```
gem 'devise', github: 'twalpole/devise', branch: 'rails5'
```

Comment: This could do with some more explanation.

Comment: This is probably outdated - that fork is 3 months old and devise master now has similar changes